# how i can fix this Please note that this file cannot be installed on Android version 12 or later

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

how i can fix this

> You have uploaded an APK file or Android application packages containing an activity, activity alias, service, or broadcast receiver with an intent filter, but without setting the 'android:exported' property. Please note that this file cannot be installed on Android version 12 or later. For more information, please go to: [developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported.)

the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:label="Restauranty"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCEe0nmCczXoq_2JXstvMpMHjbN2qntZQw"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:exported="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
            android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
            />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please uploading the gradle error message.

Comment: Check if there's any dependency containing activity, activity alias, service, or broadcast receiver with an intent filter and not having exported tag. if you find then you can define exported explicitly in manifest

Comment: It is not a error, but this response comes to me when I want to upload the application to Google Play

Comment: One or more of the libraries that you are using is violating this rule. Check the merged manifest to see which one it is. You can find the merged manifest in the "Merged Manifest" sub-tab of the `AndroidManifest.xml` editor.